# Linked cells on a network drive not updating because file location gets changed

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010, network-drive

I appreciate any help on this.

I have an Excel workbook that has a few cells linked to another workbook. It’s to a report that is in our “Shared Drive” in the BAS1 folder. When I open on my desktop, all the links in the cells show the full file path like it appears below. I did all the direct linking between the 2 workbooks on my desktop.

`\\DTCNAS-SCFM003\C_MTGBCD_Groups\BK_FC_Cent_QA_Ops_Risk\Bankruptcy QA Testing\Haas\BAS1`

But when someone else opens up the file (on a laptop for example) the links within the cell get shortened. When I open on my laptop it appears like below:

`E:\Bankruptcy QA Testing\Haas\BAS1`

So If I try to update links from a laptop it will fail because it can’t find the report location.

I’m wondering about 2 things:

1: Why when I open on my desktop is the full file path location showing vs a shortened link?

2: Since the first link location is a different letter on my desktop vs what it is for other people (ex: if I check my drives the long link is actually an F: Drive and for my boss it’s a D: Drive) how do you get around linking to a certain file location on a shared drive when the drive letters can be different for everyone that is trying to open the report?

I've read a little about the UNC (Universal Naming Convention) issues that others have had in the past but I'm not entirely sure how to implement this in my case. Would I have to figure out the User's drive letter locations every time before anyone would be able to update it somehow? I'm using the `ActiveWorkbook.UpdateLink Name:=ActiveWorkbook.LinkSources` piece of code to update outside links so I'm not sure how to combine these 2 processes.

If you have any free time I’d appreciate your thoughts on this if you have any.

Comment: Shared resources can be a pain to work with for that (and other) reasons. Avoid it if you can. Have you tried to store the link dynamically in a variable, e.g. `link =  Application.ThisWorkbook.FullName` and then updating that way instead?

Comment: Yeah this unfortunately has to pull from a report on a shared company wide network drive. I was thinking about somehow figuring out the drive letter that the user has for that directory and then storing that in a string variable and concatenating it to a set workbook name, etc. Something like that. Open to ideas though.

Comment: A possible workaround would be to loop through all possible drive letters with `On Error Resume Next` set until the shared workbook is found, since the name of the shared workbook remains the same regardless of the user. This is not a pretty solution, but it should work.

Comment: I ended up going into the sheet and just using find/replace to insert the full network path replacing the shortened F: Drive. I thought I had tried this before but it seems to have worked to set that destination across multiple computers. I made the change to the workbook on my desktop and then went in on my laptop and now the full path is showing on both.